# Drill Down Charts for iOS Swift and Android

Tags: android, ios, swift, charts, drilldown

We want to implement drill down charts for our iOS Swift App and Android App, we have done some research & implementation of different charts

**For iOS**
https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

**For Android**
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

but we unable to find drill down charts there.

Also we have license for **FusionCharts** https://www.fusioncharts.com/features/linkedcharts-for-drill-down/

but for mobile apps iOS and Android respectively UX (User eXperience) not good as expected because they provide implementation solution with WKWebView.

---

***So is there any way to implement same with best user experience and good budget?***

---

**Drill Down Charts**

Definition:
according to IBM

> Drill down charts are used to give another level of detailed reporting
>   to charts. The chart must be a bar, pie, or ring chart. Users click a
>   specific bar or segment of a chart to drill-down to a more detailed
>   report.

**Drill Down Chart Example**

[image]

Comment: I believe using danielgindi/Charts you can achieve your desired outcome for IOS, it is highly customizable and you can detect user entry touch, and open another chart while passing the data